# Email clients rendering links in plain text emails

Tags: email, text, hyperlink, email-client

If I send a plain text email from a server, which email clients are likely to render a link (in the format https://stackoverflow.com/) as a link?

Comment: Could you name your operating system/distribution?

Comment: It's the email clients I'm interested in - they could be pretty much anything but knowing the target audience, likely to be email clients available on Windows and Mac, so gmail (which does render a plain-text link as a clickable link), Outlook .... any popular email clients.